# Are webcache pages more secure?

Tags: caching

Whenever I see a suspicious looking URL I want to go to, I usually just search it up on Google's webcache and browse the site that way. But I just realized that I never really had evidence to support this kind of habit. Are web cached pages generally more safe than the original pages?

Answer (score 4):

Cached pages aren't inherently more secure, as the same page is being sent to your browser. It still renders the website in your browser.
If you need to go to a sketchy website, turning off plugins and JavaScript makes it more safe. 
In Chrome, go to Content settings and add a Deny exception for the site in Plugins and JavaScript. 
For Firefox, use the NoScript add-on.

Answer (score 3):

It is all down to what "cached" means... Since you mentioned Google Cache, a default cached version, caches the text and load external resources (potentially unsafe): **So it is by default no more secure** than accessing the webpage directly.

If you edit the cached URL however by adding `&strip=1`, **it will be more secure** by essence, because the current cached page has been stripped of external references.
Example:

- [This cached post (non-stripped)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YyB6gHe3oUEJ:security.stackexchange.com/questions/112722/are-cached-pages-more-secure%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au)
- [This cached post (stripped)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YyB6gHe3oUEJ:security.stackexchange.com/questions/112722/are-cached-pages-more-secure%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&strip=1)

If you wish to check a URL that is suspicious, I would advice doing so on a Unix/Linux (including OS X) VM then restore a snapshot.

if using a Windows computer, I would be a bit more careful, open a private session in the browser, disable Java, Flash, Silverlight and any other plugins (but the antivirus/malware agent), then access this page or use the striped cached mode.